# C# ASP.NET Range Validator only accept several value

Tags: c#, asp.net

currently I have a strange problem with RangeValidator.

I have a TextBox declared like this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" type="number"></asp:TextBox>
```

and a RangeValidator declared like this :

```
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server"
    ID="rangeValidator1"
    ErrorMessage="Insert between 1-10000"
    ControlToValidate="textBox1"
    MaximumValue="10000"
    MinimumValue="1">
```

for some reason it only valid when I entered these numbers :

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
```

the rest numbers between 1-10000 (ex.: 2-9, 11-99, etc.) simply cause the validator to fail.

why is this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in order to validator to work with a range of numbers, the Type should be declared as Integer.

this is something I miss.

```
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server"
    ID="rangeValidator1"
    ErrorMessage="Insert between 1-10000"
    ControlToValidate="textBox1"
    MaximumValue="10000"
    MinimumValue="1"
    Type="Integer">
```

Comment: You should mark this as answer if it's the answer you were looking for

Comment: I will, but SO says that I should wait for 2 days to accept my own answer

Comment: Okay then you can wait 2 days